# Can I concatenate 2 columns in my query when using SELECT in ado.net?

Tags: vb.net, linq

VS2013, vb.net

For this class (only the relevant properties are displayed):

```
Public Class UserPost
  Public Property Title As String
  Public Property Topic As String
  Public Property Type As ChannelType 'ChannelType is an Enum
End Class
```

The following query returns a simple list(of string) holding the titles of the UserPosts with Topic = topic:

```
Dim rtnList As New List(Of String)    
rtnList = db.UserPost.Where(Function(x) x.Topic = topic).Select(Function(x) x.Anchor.Title).ToList()
```

But it would be useful to also report the ChannelType as a prefix to the Title.  I could create a more complicated object to receive 2 columns and combine them later, but I wondered if there is a way to concatenate the columns in the query so that the rtnList receives the result of:

```
ChannelType.tostring() & Title
```

without having to code that afterword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is.  You just do pretty much exactly what you said.  Instead of returning `x.Anchor.Title` you return `x.Anchor.ChannelType.ToString() & x.Anchor.Title`.

Comment: That was great!  I applied the technique you gave w/o the .tostring() method and the concatenation was handled with the single query and the simple list(of string); that was the heart of my question.  However, I received this runtime error. "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."  I guess overall it interpreted my enum as a string; don't understand that.  I ended up doing a small post process, but it was still shorter than what I had initially envisioned.

Comment: A solution to the issue of LINQ to Entities not recognising that method is to throw a `ToArray` call in there before the `Select`.  It means that your L2E query will pull back the entire record rather than part of it but it means the `Select` call will use the LINQ to Objects provider rather than L2E and therefore it will be OK with calling `ToString`.